# SSO implementation at CM side with ADFS 2.0

Tags: 2013, sso

We need to implement SSO at CM side with ADFS 2.0.

Is there a documentation and reference available for same?

We try to search over the internet but there are documentation available at only for configuration with the CA SiteMinder and Tivoli Access Manager

We referred following link as well:

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_59979CAA10334D61979C34C85FA7703A

Answer (score 3):

The out-of-the-box SSO integration is intended for SSO systems that provide the user name in an HTTP header.
ADFS is not such a SSO system; it uses SAML to send a set of claims to the application.

So, the OOTB SSO integration cannot be used to integrate with ADFS. It should be possible to create an integration yourself, but that is far from trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this URL if you are on Tridion 2013

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B&addHistory=true&query=SSO&scope=&tid=04604072-0bf0-47f1-9618-05b12afd7ad9&filename=GUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DSSO&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1399376747909&currentQuery=SSO&currentScope=